# What is convention/best practice to organize passing data from buttons in multiple children, to a parent in ReactJS, using only hook useState?

Tags: reactjs

I've read best practice is to pass data from parent down to children, and pass data up as needed.  I also want to do "best practice" in terms of others being able to easily read and maintain code.

I have a "shopping cart", and an "item list" with controls that increase or decrease the count of that item in the cart.  Both items are in a "parent" element.

Into that parent element, I plan to import an array of "item" objects, and add a "count" key/value to each object to indicate how many of that item is on the cart.  I also add an "arrayIndex" key/value to indicate what index of the item array an item is at.  I use that modified array of "item" objects, sending to "shopping cart" and "item list".  I also write button functions in that parent element and pass them to "item list" through props.

When a button in "item list" is pressed, it calls the function that's passed down through props.  That function updates state.

The "tricky" part is, when a button in "item list" is pressed, I reference the arrayIndex.  I use this to reference what object to change in the modified array of "item" objects.  But when I do this, I feel I may not be following best practices.  Each button is effectively tied to a particular array of data objects.  But even if an array is of thousands of objects, I figure array modifications are done by index reference, and React doesn't re-render unnecessary components, so it should still be pretty fast.

An alternative is to create an empty array in "shopping cart" and use "item list" controls to modify that array.  That feels more modular, as it doesn't tie a button to a particular array of data objects.  But it's also odd, as I'm not passing data down from parent to child; I'm passing a function from parent to child that the child uses to modify data in parent, then pass data from the parent to another child.

Is there a convention / best practice for moving data around in React; if so, where would I find more info?  (perhaps a link?). Or am I overlooking something big in terms of one approach being more effective (less time or less memory?)

(I'm doing this as part of an exercise where I'm only using useState.)

Looked at airbnb style guide for React/JSX, looked for best practices for React, but didn't find any definitive answer for the context.